# How to show in Android with kotlin, the "someone calling" screen when app is closed or fone in idle like when someone call? For a video call

Tags: android, kotlin

I working in a internal chat application with video calls, when someone call, the phone must show the "ringing" screen. I need to wake up the phone screen and show the full screen notification with the calling screen when the app receives a push notification that someone is calling.

How can I do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `TelephonyManager` to give you access to a subset of API's available natively.

Once you create an instance of this, you must register to `listen()` passing in a class that implements the PhoneStateListener. From here you can listen to a numerous states when listening for the `LISTEN_CALL_STATE`

Something like this:

```
private var yourListenerClass: ListenerClass? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     var telephonyManager = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
     telephonyManager?.listen(yourListenerClass, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE)
}

private inner class ListenerClass : PhoneStateListener() {
     override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int, number: String?) {
          super.onCallStateChanged(state, number)
          when (state) {
            TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING-> {
               //incoming call detected, do something
            }
            TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE-> {
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Here is the resource to the documentation that can give you more API's available for this listener: [onCallStateChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener#onCallStateChanged(int,%20java.lang.String))